# Which Linux should I go for my old pc

Tags: dual-boot

I have a pc with 512 mb ram and 1.6ghz and duron processor and 40gb hard disk. I have tried to install Ubuntu, Linux mint,lubuntu but everytime it shows error. Kernel exitted with error. 
Only Linux puppy found to be running on it but every software which I tried to install example chrome, Firefox etc get crashed all the time. So what should I be doing now.

Comment: No matter which flavor of *buntu you try it will show some kind of problem on 512 RAM. You can run Lubuntu for your RAM size but have to keep away from high memory footprint applications like Chrome, as they demand a decent share of memory to run smoothly. My suggestion if you dont want to upgrade your hardware is use applications which are light on memory.

Comment: I would say, take out the hard drive, connect it to some other machine and using that machine , install Lubuntu or Xubuntu. These two are lightweight enough for that purpose. RAM strongly would be suggested to increase, but if you cannot, use larger swap partition. That can be configured during installation in "Something else" option. also I'd suggest using `blackbox` or `openbox` desktops as alternative; they are very light

Answer (score 0):

You can do . But which purpose you do install,

You desire the functionality of your old computer, 
If you want operate Web server, samba. I recommend Zentyal.

If you need development Process or R&D your Linux system , 
Its shouldn't comfortable.

Try with Ubuntu Desktop. Its so fun.